# Insert new line in txt file when found a semicolon

Tags: ruby

I have a txt file from a cc of a emails like this: jhon@example;phil@exampl1.com;hon@example;phil@exampl1.com;hon@example;phil@exampl1.com

```
File.open("emails.txt").readlines.each do |line|
 puts line;
end
```

And in my code I can read a line and output it but I don't know how to found a semicolon and make a break line so I can get a text like this:

- jhon@example;
- jhon@example;
- jhon@example;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`readlines` takes an optional separator argument. Use a semicolon as your separator:

```
File.open("emails.txt").readlines(';').each do |line|
  puts line
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str=File.open("fn.txt") {|f| f.read.gsub(";","\n")}
File.open("fn.txt","w"){|f| f.write(str) }
```

I'd write to a different file than the source file though